# Access adding records from one table

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table EmpRequirements, the fields are:

```
EmpRequirementsID (AutoNumber), 
EmpID (from the Employees Table), 
RequirementID (from the Requirement Table), 
RequirementName (from the Requirement Table), 
Received_OnFile (Check), 
NotApplicable (Check), 
DateReceived (Date), 
ExpirationDate (Date)
```

What I want to do is have a Button (Add Requirements) that on Click will add all of the data from Requirement Table (Requirement ID, and RequirementName) for the Employee that is current on my form. If I add a Requirement I would like to be able to click the Button and it will add any and all Requirements to that employee that currently do not exist for that employee.
This would then show up in the form as a Subform datasheet where the user can then edit all of the other fields in the EmpRequirements.
I have tried to use Append and Update and to date have not come up with the answer. I wonder if this could be just an easy Macro to write.

I have tried to add the records using this statement, I have ' out the error handler, and am getting the run time error 3134 - syntax error insert into statement

```
Private Sub Add_Click()

'  On Error GoTo Err_Add_Click

    Dim strSQL1 As String

    strSQL1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO [EmpRequirements]( [EmpID], [RequirementID], [RequirementName] )" & _
          "SELECT DISTINCT [Employees].[EmpID], [Requirement].[RequirementID], [Requirement].[RequirementName]" & _
          "FROM [Employees], [Requirement]  " & _
          "WHERE (((Employees.EmpID)=[Forms]![Employee Details]![EmpID]));"

   DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL1

 [Forms]![Employee Details].Refresh          'Refresh after update EmpRequirements Subform

'Exit_Add_Click:                             ' Label to resume after error.
'     Exit Sub                               ' Exit before error handler.
'Err_Add_Click:                              ' Label to jump to on error.
'     MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description    ' Place error handling here.
'     Resume Exit_Add_Click                  ' Pick up again and quit.


End Sub
```

Will this work and can you help with the error?

Comment: I have tried to use this statement to update the table

Comment: Access does not support `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: Very much appreciate the info

Comment: I know that if I remove the "Ignore" it will add the records and not any duplicates, however does try to add all records and of course since I have set the table [EmpRequirements].[EmpID] and [EmpRequirements].[RequirementID] as key fields it won't add the duplicates. What I would like to do is ignore the duplicates and add only the new records. Am I missing a line in the code that would use "Not Exists" Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I came up with

Private Sub Add_Click()

On Error GoTo errHandler

```
Dim strSQL1 As String

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

strSQL1 = "INSERT INTO EmpRequirements ( EmpID, RequirementID, RequirementName ) " & _
            "SELECT SQ1.EmpID, SQ1.RequirementID, SQ1.RequirementName " & _
            "FROM (SELECT Employees.EmpID, Requirement.RequirementID, Requirement.RequirementName " & _
            "FROM Employees, Requirement WHERE (((Employees.EmpID)=[Forms]![Employee Details]![EmpID]))) " & _
            "AS SQ1 LEFT JOIN EmpRequirements ON (SQ1.EmpID=EmpRequirements.EmpID) " & _
            "AND (SQ1.RequirementID= EmpRequirements.RequirementID) " & _
            "WHERE EmpRequirements.RequirementID IS NULL;"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL1

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

[Forms]![Employee Details].Refresh                                     'Refresh after update EmpRequirements Subform

Exit Sub                                                                ' Exit before error handler.

errHandler:                                                             ' Label to jump to on error.
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & " in " & _
        VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule, vbOKOnly, "Error"

End Sub

Thanks all